# how to properly redirect from one app to another app in django

Tags: python, django, redirect, url-pattern

i am a beginner to Django and i am unable to properly handle redirects from one app to another. I have 2 apps Accounts, Dashboard. Accounts Handles login and registration of AuthUser. Dashboard handles other functionality like Fileupload

So far, I have successfully using reverse() method have redirected from /accounts/login to my upload page but it redirects from /accounts/login to /accounts/upload instead of /dashboard/upload .

**Project URLS**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('dashboard/', include('Dashboard.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('Accounts.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**Account urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    url('upload',DashboardViews.upload, name='upload'),
    path('login', views.login, name='Login'),
    path('register', views.register, name='Register'),
    path('logout', views.logout, name='logout')
]
```

**Account views.py**

```py
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'login.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':

        user_name = request.POST.get("username")
        password = request.POST.get("password")

        user = auth.authenticate(username=user_name,password=password)

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request,user)
            return redirect(reverse('upload'))
        else:
            print('Failed') 
            return render(request,'login')
```

My intention is whenever user (login/register), web page should redirect from /account/login to /dashboard/upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have the **upload** url defined in the urlpatterns of your **Accounts** app.
You should place it in the urls.py file from the **Dashboard** app if you want the full path to be **/dashboard/upload**, instead of **/accounts/upload**.

To explain it a bit more, when you define a path with the **include** function, like this:

```py
   path("accounts/", include("Accounts.urls")
```

All the urls from the Accounts app will have "accounts/" appended at the beginning.

Note: If you add the **name** parameter to a **path**, you can use it in **all** your **apps** with the **reverse** function. The path doesn't have to be declared in the same app where you want to call the reverse function.

A good practice to avoid having url conflicts is to add the name of the app to the url. So you should maybe name the **upload** path as **dashboard_upload**.

Comment: this is my **Dashboard\urls.py**
`urlpatterns = [
    path('upload', views.upload, name='upload'),
    path('reports', views.reports, name='reports')
]`

Comment: I updated my answer, you should remove the upload url from your Accounts app because they have the same name and it's causing a conflict. When you use reverse it searches for the first url with that name.

Comment: Thank you so much solved the problem. I removed the upload path from the Accounts url.py file.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem, but below technique worked for me.

In your `urls.py` file of `Dashboard` app, use `app_name = "Dashboard"`. then in your `redirect()` function use appName:Path structure. For example, use `redirect('Dashboard:upload')`